# Editing shadow file to change root password

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, root

I was trying to change the root password for a CTF.

- I had access to  www-data account
- Couldn't use the sudo command but did escalate my privileges to root.

I was trying to change the shadow file to change the root password. It had a $6$hash and i used the

`openssl passwd -6 newpassword`

to create a new hash and replaced the line for the root in the shadow file.
Even after doing all that i was still unable to ssh into the root account.
(Yes password was enabled for root and i also tried deleting the 'x' in the /etc/passwd file.)

Comment: SSH can implement additional restrictions on root. You may need to modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart ssh, or create a regular user account to ssh and then use su to escallate your privs (or modify sudoers or....)

Comment: Even if ssh does allow root access it may only allow public key auth, in which case you wluld create a private and public key pair and add the lublic key to ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: login using both password and public key was allowed. Either way let me check the sshd_config file to make sure there are no restrictions.

Comment: Is there any other reason why the password may not be changing? Like,      [1] is changing the /etc/passwd file or the shadow file no longer a way to change the password?          [2]or is deleting the x in the passwd file still a valid way to disable the password?

Comment: ssh public key might be mandatory and authorized_keys file not be in standard place (not `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` ) see sshd_config